# How to create an image swiper in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Right now in our app we are able to scroll images in a ScrollView but the images get stuck in between the scrolling.  I would like to make it to where when scrolling if the user doesn't scroll the image all the way over the app finishes the job for them and the image snaps into place.  I want to be able to calculate how much the image slides over and in what direction but I am having trouble find ways to do this.  Do anyone know an easy way to do this?

```
<ScrollView style={{borderRadius: 7}}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    scrollEventThrottle={10}
    pagingEnabled
    onScroll={
        Animated.event(
            [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this.calcImgPosition()}}}]
        )
    }
>
    {imageArray}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think you can use this library, https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `react-native-swiper-flatlist` component. It's fairly simple to use and the documentation is good (https://github.com/gusgard/react-native-swiper-flatlist).

Answer (score 1):

If you want use multiple images via link, then [react-native-image-swiper](https://github.com/7772/react-native-image-swiper) will help to you.

#### So simple usage.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import ImagesSwiper from "react-native-image-swiper";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const customImg = [
  "https://..",       // img link 1
  "https://...",      // img link 2
  "https://...."      // img link 3
  // ..
];

<ImagesSwiper 
  images={customImg}
  width={width} 
  height={height - 400} 
/>
```